# How can I write linq lambda with high performance avoiding low performance sql query?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I am writing some linq query They are great at the begining of the project, but when clients getting alot, My application's performance got stuck always. When I check created sql result I realized that producing "IN" clause queries creating this trouble? How can I improve below linq query avoding low performance result? I think I need CTE result instead of "IN".

C# with linq:

```py
  if (includexyzReferance)
            {
                xyzReferanceList = xyzReferenceService.Isxxx<Product>(productIds.Select(a => a.ToString()));
            }
```

Low Performance Sql Result:

```py
    SELECT [p].[ReferencedxyzId]
      FROM [Common].[xyzReference] AS [p]
     WHERE ([p].[IsDeleted] = 0) 
       AND (([p].[ReferencedxyzType] = @__refxyzType_0) 
       AND [p].[ReferencedxyzId] IN (N'2169', N'2168', N'1084', N'1076', N'1075', N'1074', N'1073', N'1071', N'1070', N'1069', N'1068', N'1067'))
```

How can I improve it? How can I rearrange my linq for best performance?
Thanks alot!

Comment: You might have better luck on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.  This site isn't really for questions about improving performance because that's such a subjective thing.  It's more for errors in code, coding utilities, etc.

Comment: is `ReferencedEntityId` an `nvarchar`? it looks int-ish? But: if it is a perf-critical code-path, consider writing the SQL yourself, and use either EF or something like Dapper to invoke your SQL (avoiding the need to touch raw ADO.NET); Dapper has some nice tricks for `in` queries that EF doesn't have, AFAIK

Comment: Firstly, are you sure that ReferencedEntityId is a string? Secondly, have you added appropriate indexes to your database. Thirdly, have you considered writing a stored procedure on the SQL server, and calling that?